# Set Pointer to Hand when hovering over UI element in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have an Image, which is attached to some JavaScript on MouseEnter.

This all works fine. When user "Mouses Over", JS is called and storyboard runs as expected.

I also want to change the mouse cursor to a "Hand Pointer" when the user hovers over, probably I guess, this occurs in the same JS function.

Also, how do I change it back?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question again:

Turns out there is a Hand attribute I missed.

```
<Image Canvas.Left="719.732" x:Name="img17_18" Width="180" Height="208.09" Source="Padmamand1.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="36.91" Opacity="0.595" Cursor="Hand"/>
```

Sweet.